# Getting catcomplete to work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to implement the categories version of autocomplete in jquery.

This is the type of array I need to recreate and pass to my view:

```
var data = [
  { label: "anders", category: "" },
  { label: "andreas", category: "" },
  { label: "antal", category: "" },
  { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
  { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
  { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
  { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
  { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
  { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
];
```

Currently, my controller fetches all the foods from the database and created a new array that contains only one attribute from the objects in the original array.

I need to grab more than just one attribute in this newly created array...

Here's what it looks like in my controller:

```
  @foods = Food.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  render json: @foods.map(&:name)
```

That code only sends the name attribute of each food object. I need it to send both the name and the type in order to get jquerys catcomplete to work.

How can I do this?

I've tried using some of the following in irb to see the results (without the @ obv):

```
@foods.map(&:name) is the same as @foods.map do {|t| t.name}

@foods.map do |t|
    t.name
    t.type
end

@foods.collect do |t|

@foods.each_slice(2).map {|name, type| Array.new(name, type)}

@foods.each_slice(2).map {|n, t| n.name, t.type }

@foods.map do |t|
   @foods.map do |i|
     i.name
   end
   @foods.map do |p|
     p.name
   end
end
```

and probably a dozen other variations...

Here is how I'm passing the array around:

View:

```
 <%= text_field_tag 'search_food_text_field', nil, data: { catcomplete_source: search_foods_path } %>
```

Foods_Controller

```
def search
  @foods = Food.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  render json: @foods.map do |food|
    {name: food.name, type: food.type }
  end
end
```

foods.js

```
$(function() {

  $( "#search_food_text_field" ).catcomplete({
    source: $("#search_food_text_field").data('catcomplete-source')
  });

});
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the search is done asynchronously

Comment: What does your json output look like?

Comment: Hmmm. When I was including all the search data into the view before searching I would be able to tell you... Although now that I'm getting it from the controller I wouldn't be able to say. I *can* say that it *is* outputting the right values with the code I posted here. I just need to add the "type" attribute in as well. It's easy to do it with the code on the JQuery site http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories check the source to see what I mean

Comment: @Raghu It only outputs the name of the object. It doesn't give any other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Logan Serman and Eru's help I was able to solve this issue.

Jquery was looking for "label" and "type" and I was providing "name" and "type" which is why the textfield only displayed the type.

This got it to work.

```
 def search
   @foods = Food.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
   render json: @foods.map{|t| {type: t.type, label: t.name}}
 end
```

In case anyone is wondering... this is what the json output looks like:

[{"type":"MealFood","label":"Sample Food"}]

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
@foods.map do |food|
  { name: food.name, type: food.type }
end
```

is what you want. This will map each value of the array to a hash, so you end up with an array of hashes, each containing the name and type.

```
def search
  @foods = Food.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").all
  @foods_catcomplete = @foods.map do |food|
    { name: food.name, type: food.type }
  end
  render json: @foods_catcomplete
end
```

Comment: this looks like it should be working in irb... I'm not sure why it's not. I've been trying to do exactly this all day! lol Thanks for your answer. 
also, in case your wondering, the result is a blank feed. My server says it's loading the foods though... 
If I use the sample data, it renders in the search box perfectly.

Comment: This method won't magically change in your app. If it works in irb, it works in your app. There must be some other problem. How are you retrieving the results? Ajax? How are you returning the response in your controller?

Comment: I included the code snippets to try and answer your question. I'm not sure if that's AJAX.

Comment: Visit search_foods_path in your browser. Does it return the correct JSON array?

Comment: it's not giving me the same array I get in irb. It's giving all the other information as well.

Comment: if I change it back to @foods.map(&:name) it renders the correct array for *that* command

Comment: I found that this renders a bit more correct "render json: @foods.map{|t| {name: t.name, type: t.type}} "

But it's still off.. this is the JSON output "{"name":"Sample Food","type":"MealFood"}"

Comment: Yes I was going to suggest a one-liner like in my edit. I think that the multi line block is confusing the Ruby parser when using `render` without parentheses. Can you use my search method in the edit, maybe uncommenting the puts line to see what is generated in the console? I don't see how your example is giving back a hash instead of an array. `map` will always return an array.

Comment: This is the output of the edit {"name":"Sample Food","type":"MealFood"}

Comment: Try appending `.all` to the where clause. See my edit. Also view the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253238/ruby-array-to-json-and-rails-json-rendering you can see that the solution is the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

if you render as json it will take only one json object, not the array. Use:

```
render text: @foods.map{|t| {name: t.name, type: t.type}}
```

Comment: Great! This creates the array right, but now the textfield doesn't render anything at all. The array looks like this though [{:name=>"Sample Food", :type=>"MealFood"} which is what I thought was needed.

Comment: I think the issue is that jquery is expecting "label" instead of "name"

Comment: so put label instead of name: `.map {|t| {label: t.name, type: t.type}}`