# Ruby datamapper associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I am just learning Ruby and datamapper, I have read the docs about associations from the official DataMapper site, but I still have two problems.
First whenever I add associated object, I can not see it when displaying all objects.
I have test class like:

```
class Test
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  has 1, :phonen, :through => Resource
end
```

And then phonen class like:

```
class Phonen
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :number, String
  belongs_to :test
end
```

Then I am creating those 2 objects

```
@test = Test.create(
  :name => "Name here"
)

@phone = Phonen.create(
  :number => "Phone number"
)

@test.phonen = @phone
@test.save
```

And I want to display them like that (I want to return json)

```
get '/' do
  Test.all.to_json
end
```

What am I doing wrong? maybe its something with the `to_json`...
I honestly don't know..
But I have one additional question to this topic, lets say I managed to connect those two classes, if I display JSON will I get `Phonen { }` or just inside class `{ }`?
I know its probably very easy question, but I can't figure it out. That's why I decided to ask you guys. Thanks for help

Comment: You won't get the association nested, you will have to create a serializer or a view in order to recreate the phonen inside of the Test class. Perhaps you can read something about jbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Test.all
Is returning an active record association in array form, not a hash, when you try to convert to json it's failing.

You can try:

```
render json: Test.all
```

As asked in this question:

[Ruby array to JSON and Rails JSON rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253238/ruby-array-to-json-and-rails-json-rendering)